# How to use an user input as a regex?

Tags: regex, perl, input

I have a simple program where the user can enter a string.
After this the user can enter a regex. I need the string to be compared against this regex.

The following code do not work - the regex always fails.

And I know that its maybe because I am comparing a string with a string and not a string with a regex.

But how would you do this?

```
while(1){
    print "Enter a string: ";
    $input = <>;
    print "\nEnter a regex and see if it matches the string: ";
    $regex = <>;

    if($input =~ $regex){
        print "\nThe regex $regex matched the string $input\n\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `//`, `m//`, or `s///` — but you can specify a variable as the pattern.

```
if ($input =~ /$regex/) {
  print "match found\n";
}
```

Comment: @NikhilJain, I was talking about the syntax required in general:  if you use `=~` or `!~` then you need to apply it to a matching type of operator.

Comment: yes, actually I thought the same thing that you are providing the options in general that's why I deleted my comment.

Comment: your solution works. As regex i entered /something_to_match/ where i just should type something_to_match without /.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use [lexical variables](http://p3rl.org/my) instead of global ones.
2. You should remember that strings read by [`<>`](http://p3rl.org/readline) usually contain newlines, so it might be necessary to remove the newlines with [`chomp`](http://p3rl.org/chomp), like this:

   ```
   chomp(my $input = <STDIN>);
   chomp(my $regex = <STDIN>);
   ```
3. You might want to interpret regex special characters taken from the user literally, so that `^` will match a literal circumflex, not the beginning of the string, for example. If so, use the [`\Q`](http://p3rl.org/quotemeta) escape sequence:

   ```
   if ($input =~ /\Q$regex\E/) { ... }
   ```
4. Don't forget to read the [Perl FAQ](http://faq.perl.org) in your journey through Perl. It might have all the answers before you even begin to specify the question: [How do I match a regular expression that's in a variable?](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-match-a-regular-expression-thats-in-a-variable-)

Comment: Thx for the fast reply :) But i still cant get this to work :(. The string wont match the regex.

Comment: Could you provide that string and regex?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to chomp input and regex variables. and correct the expression to match regex

```
chomp( $input );
chomp( $regex );
if($input =~ /$regex/){
    print "\nThe regex $regex matched the string $input\n\n";
}
```